# How to stop the creation of a table when mapping to a stored proc MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have a codefirst MVC 5 application. There is a spatial query involved, which I have wrapped in a stored proc.

Using a new class, I've mapped the results of the stored proc call to a Model to use in my views.

However, codefirst wants to create a new table for the model class. How do I prevent that? Should I even bother (I'm never writing to the table or updating the table.)

Model class:

```
public class Conflict
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int ConflictProjectId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [Display(Name="Start")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [Display(Name = "End")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

}
```

Stored proc call:

```
public ActionResult Index(int d = 0, int r = 0, int p = 0, bool future = false)
{
    var dayBufferParameter = new SqlParameter("@daybuffer", d);
    var distBufferParameter = new SqlParameter("@distbuffer", r);

    var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<Conflict>("GetAllConflicting @daybuffer, @distbuffer",
        dayBufferParameter, distBufferParameter)
        .Where(proj => p == 0 || proj.ProjectId == p)
        .Where(proj => !future || proj.EndDate >= DateTime.Now).ToList();

    return View(result);
}
```

DBContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<n.Models.Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<n.Models.Conflict> Conflicts { get; set; }
}
```

Generated migration (WHAT I DON'T WANT!):

```
public partial class conflicts : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Conflicts",
            c => new
                {
                    ProjectId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ConflictProjectId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    StartDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    EndDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.ProjectId, t.ConflictProjectId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Projects", t => t.Project_ProjectId)
            .Index(t => t.ConflictProject_ProjectId)
            .Index(t => t.Project_ProjectId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Conflicts", "Project_ProjectId", "dbo.Projects");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Conflicts", "ConflictProject_ProjectId", "dbo.Projects");
        DropIndex("dbo.Conflicts", new[] { "Project_ProjectId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Conflicts", new[] { "ConflictProject_ProjectId" });
        DropTable("dbo.Conflicts");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it'll work, but have you tried decorating your Conflict class with the NotMapped attribute?

Comment: Seems to work. I had to recreate the migrations though.

Comment: If you don't want Conflict Model to be in your migration, you can just remove dbSet<Models.Conflict> Conflicts in your ApplicationDBContext